# Get duplicate keys from array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an array like following and I need to detect all the duplicate keys, not values.

```
$array1 = array(
    "a"             => "Mike",
    "b"             => "Charles",
    "b"             => "Robert",
    "c"             => "Joseph"
);
```

All the functions I've used are focused on values, and If I apply flip_array(), it's automatically deleting the duplicate keys.

Comment: You can't! If you define it like that the duplicate keys just get overwritten!

Comment: Edited my answer in order to provide a working solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the answer provided by @TechTreeDev, this is the function  I made to show the duplicate keys and values from array.  [**Working demo at IDEOne**](https://ideone.com/TVELvl).

The parameter `textOfArray()` will be the array's content on simple quotes.

```
function findCoincidences($textOfArray) {
    $output = "";

    // Locate all the duplicated Strings (keys and values)
    preg_match_all('/".*?"/', $textOfArray, $matches);

    // Make array where key = string, and value = repetitions
    $arrayCoinc = array_count_values($matches[0]);

    $output = "==== COINCIDENCES  ====<br>";
    foreach ($arrayCoinc as $k => $v){
        if ($v > 1){
            $output .= "<b>".$k."</b> Found:".$v."<br>";
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
echo findCoincidences($array1);
```

Result:

```
==== COINCIDENCES ====
"a" Found:4
"f" Found:3
"e" Found:3
```

Comment: Great answer, this should be the accepted one!  I tested it out at a demo sandbox and added the sandbox link to your answer, hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 11):

[Array](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php)-Keys are never duplicates, as they're unique identifiers. (Like Database primary keys)

Declaring `$array['b']` twice will cause overriding of the first value.

> If multiple elements in the array declaration use the same key, only the last one will be used as all others are overwritten.

Following your logic `print_r($array1['b'])` would output 2 values, which is impossible.

---

If you want mulpile values for a key add a dimension:

```
$array1 = array(
    "a"             => "Mike",
    "b"             => array(1 => "Charles", 2 => "Robert"),
    "c"             => "Joseph"
);
```

`print_r($array1['b']);`

will return

`Array ( [1] => Charles [2] => Robert )`

---

**EDIT**

If there's no way around you have to use regular expressions with [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php) and your array as string:

```
$array1 =' array(
    "a"             => "Mike",
    "b"             => "Charles",
    "b"             => "Robert",
    "c"             => "Joseph"
)';
preg_match_all('/([A-Z])\w+/', $array1, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

will return

```
 Array ( [0] => Mike [1] => Charles [2] => Robert [3] => Joseph )
```

Comment: My porpuse is to correct a huge array I entried manually, used to translate strings with gettext. Now I may have some key repeated.

Comment: Then you have to change the keys manually, as they're overwritten if you do something with it. Otherwise write a regex Function and provide the Array as string and create a new key index for the array (0-xxx). But this issue isn't in the scope of the question. Hope this helped you still.

Comment: Thanks! I will convert the array to string, and somehow look for string coincidences, I'll post it then.

Comment: It returns me preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given.

Comment: Did you add the single quotes? Or did you use $array1 twice?